# employee contract methods for working in multiple countries

Tags: employment, international

What are legal methods of writing an employee contract so that an employee of one company can work in multiple coutries? Eg one week in country A, one week in country B, one week in country C, etc.

Comment: Europeans do this all the time...

Answer (score 1):

Nothing special other than saying it is required in the contract. For example, such contracts are typical for airplane pilots and flight attendants.

The hard questions are not what a contract has to say to do it.

The hard questions, instead, are whether what the contract provides for is allowed by the immigration laws of the countries where the employee is to work, what tax implications the employment relationship has for the employee and the employer, and what choice of law decisions arise from this with regard to labor law (when the law of the company's headquarters applies, and when the laws of a particular place of work applies).